# Transformation from domains to half-spaces

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, ap.analysis-of-pdes

In a paper I read, an elliptic boundary value problem
on a bounded domain D x (0,T) is solved by first transforming
it in a set of equations on half-spaces R^n and then applying
partial Fourier transform. Eventually one single ODE is obtained.
It is not explained how this transformation is done and
it seems very mysterious to me. Can someone please give
references for this approach?
I am also interested if it is possible in general
for a single evolution equation to be transformed 
in system of equations on half spaces.
Thank you for all replies.

Comment: Could you give a reference to the paper in question? It would make it a lot easier to provide some sort of answer.

Comment: I have to agree with @Harald. Does T represent a time parameter here? 

Comment: Mary Ann Horn:"Sharp trace regularity..", Journal of Math.Systems,
Estimation and Control, vol.8, No2, 1998.
Yes T is time variable.
In which volume of Hörmander book is this explained?
I didn't find anything in the first one. 

Answer (score 2):

The half spaces R^n are the inward-pointing halves of the tangent spaces to the points on the boundary.
Starting with a local boundary value problem you end up with a model equation on the half space associated to each point on the boundary by "localizing" at the point.
A solution to the elliptic boundary value problem would give you also a solution to each of these model problems.
Conversely, you can construct a formal solution to the elliptic boundary value problem *at the boundary* by using these model problems.
Then you can improve this formal solution to an `honest' solution by solving away the error; this is easier because you no longer have to worry about the boundary.

This system of ODEs is used to state the Lopatinski-Shapiro condition, and searching for this will yield many references. My favorite is Hormander's analysis of partial differential operators -- this topic in particular is best explained in the first edition.